# Habitat requirements of black ant Lasius niger

Tags: entomology, ant, habitat

Does anyone know of any published information on the maximum slope angle and/or minimum soil depth on which the black ant *Lasius niger* will build its nests? I have read that they won't nest on "a slope that is too steep", but what does this constitute in numerical terms?